# PHP DateTime->sub() wont bubble up to days

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

If `DateTime $serverTime` is e.g. `2016-02-03 00:30:00` and i subtract 90 minutes like this

```
$serverTime->sub(new DateInterval("PT1H30M"));
```

the `$serverTime` is now `2016-02-03 23:00:00`. Notice that the date remains February 3rd. While it's exepcted that it goes down by one - it should be `2016-02-02 23:00:00`. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://3v4l.org/BCVZd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing something wrong or modifying it along the way:

```
$serverTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-02-03 00:30:00');
print_r($serverTime);
$serverTime->sub(new DateInterval("PT1H30M"));
print_r($serverTime);
```

Works fine for me: [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f87f09824d52f6c6eb7debb8252c2b17965e44c).